# Exclude Thumbs.db from Sencha Cmd build

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

When executing "sencha app build production", I receive the following error message:

```
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: Cannot find file : C:\apache24\htdoc
s\extjs\myapp\build\production\myapp\resources\images\Thumbs.db (Access denied)
```

I know that the answer could be "use a system tool to close the file handle". But I am tired of doing so, and since the Thumbs.db files are useless, I'd like to exclude copying them from the build process - once and for all times.

I tried via app.json, where I found an exclude for svn files:

```
"resources": [
    "resources/images"
],
"ignore": [
    "\.svn$",
    "\.db$"
],
```

but that didn't yield the expected result. Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @pagep I had to disable the creation of thumbs.db files in Windows to solve this.

Comment: I see, thanks. But I think there has to be some way to have ignore list :(